# Firebase authentication in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Iam using these @angular/fire official package from firebase.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

I have done login by using authentication from firebase.it works fine..but after login I navigate into routing modules..It shows login form again at time and come back into my modules..Whats the solution for to prevent showing login form again during navigating lazyloading modules after authentication..Anybody gives a solution it would be a help.!!Here is my code below

```
app.component.html

<ng-container *ngIf="afAuth.user | async as user; else showLogin">
    <div><app-header-component></app-header-component></div>
    <div><app-sidenav-component></app-sidenav-component></div>
    <mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="loading" class="spinner" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #showLogin>
    <div class="login-main">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="logo"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.jpg"
                    style="width: 120px; height: 40px;" /></div>
            <mat-card>
                <div class="title">
                    Sign in your Account
                </div>
                <form [formGroup]="login_form">
                    <div class="login-form">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                            <input matInput placeholder="Enter Your Email" type="email" name="email" formControlName="email" required>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="login_form.get('email').touched && this.login_form.get('email').hasError('required')">Email required.</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                            <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                            <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Enter Your password" name="password" formControlName="password"
                                required>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="login_form.get('email').touched && this.login_form.get('email').hasError('required')">Password Required.</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-btn">
                        <div class=""><button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="login()">Login</button></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>

app.component.ts

constructor( public afAuth : AngularFireAuth,
     private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.login_form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
login() {
    this.email = this.login_form.get('email').value;
    this.password = this.login_form.get('password').value;
    console.log("Email", this.email);
    console.log("Password", this.password);
    this.afAuth && this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        // alert("welcome to dashboard");
        window.location.reload();
        // this.isloggedin = result;
        // console.log("Logged In",this.loggedin);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error) {
          alert('invalid Credentials');
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `app.component.ts`, you can check if a user is already logged in and navigate to the page that you want:

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(){
 if(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser != null){
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/home");
  }
else{
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
}
```

Comment: I fixed it by storing session storage to check user login or not..Anyway,Thanks for coming to help